# How should I move the redis account info to mysql?

Tags: mysql, redis, refactoring

The account info contains the parts, one is stored in mysql, the other is stored in redis using hash type.

Because the redis part is growing so fast that the memory is almost used up, so it needs to move to mysql.

The mysql part is the account table with 50 fields, including 8 fields using text data type to store json serialized string.

The redis part contains 31 fields.

One need to mention is that the model use 'select * from account' and 'hgetall account_info' to get the account info.

For example, if I just want to get the account's name, it will execute 'select * from account'. if I just want to get the account's game_counts, it will execute 'hgetall account_info'

How should I move the redis account info to mysql, a new table or add columns to the existed account table?

By the way, the project is running well for many years.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use mysql to storage your data, and redis just to speed up your request.

So, you can add hot and infrequent update data into redis. In addition:

- if you just want to get the account's name, you should 'select name from account' or 'hget account name', don't use 'select *' or 'hgetall account'

Comment: It's a project running for many years, if I want to change to use select field from account, it has to change everywhere using account object and knows which fields are needed, that's a lot of work.

Comment: The question is if moving the redis part to mysql, the account table fields number will grow up to 81, that's a lot.

Comment: You can migrate your data from redis to mysql step by step. 
First, you can migrate the field that take up big space, if you think your table fileds too more, you can vertical table.